# How to implement nslookup to get client Computer name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nslookup

My website is in an `intranet network`. I get client Ip Address using following code:

```
string result=  HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Now I want to retrieve `client computer name` with Ip Address. I can get `Client Computer name` with `nslookup IpAddress` in command prompt. I want to implement `nslookup` in my asp.net website.

How can I do it?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe executing nslookup in client side

Comment: Maybe? You're not sure?

Comment: is it possible running nslookup with javascript? I don't think so.

Comment: no it's not possible to run nslookup with JavaScript. nslookup would need to be run server side, javascript is client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dns.GetHostEntry using your client IP to get the hostname from the DNS server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This link contains your answer: [System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4f2f8a38-6739-4143-926b-55e847680232/how-to-get-the-client-computer-name-in-c?forum=winforms)

More info about this link:

Using the following code you can get the hostname of the clients machine:

```
string myHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

Comment: An answer containing only a link is not an answer. Explain the solution clearly!

Comment: More info is added to my post.